# Identifying poles or essential singularities

Tags: complex-analysis

I have three functions I need to Identify whether they have poles or essential singularities of at a certain point. Here's what I have

1. $\displaystyle e^{e^z}$ at $z= \infty$
2. $\displaystyle \frac{1}{e^{e^z}-e}$ at $z=0$
3. $\displaystyle z^2 \left( \sin \frac{1}{z^2} \right)^3$ at $z=0$

What I know so far: the first two go to infinity at the given points, so I believe this makes them poles but don't completely understand what an essential singularity is? The third one goes to zero but has a weird oscillating behavior before that. Is what that's going considered an essential singularity? All help is appreciated!

Comment: $e^{e^z}$ goes to $1$ as $z$ goes to infinity along the negative real axis, so the first thing you know, isn't so.

Comment: A singularity which is not a pole or  removable one is essential. In each case see if you have a pole or  removable singularity.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I may have made a stupid mistake but I don't think any of them are removable

Comment: @NazMiheisi my sincerest apologies, I looked too quickly. Nice job on that catch. You are correct. Two should be essential

Comment: Can anyone explain how to determine whether or not these are poles/removable?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thanks! Although I actually think two are poles...

Comment: @NazMiheisi 2 is definitely a pole. 3 is definitely essential (consider a diagonal path to origin for example)... Recall $\sin(1/z)$ has an essential singularity, the logic is the same (and we would need at least $z^6$ in front to counter that). The first one should have an essential singularity at infinity, because e^(1/z) has an essential singularity at zero (and exponentiating shouldn't affect that).

Comment: @boudreaux take a limit and see if it's finite. If it's removable we can define the point to equal that limit and preserve continuity (it's a tad more than that in general, but that's essentially it). A pole blows up in absolute value but has finite negative powers in the Laurent Series about the blowup point. An essential singularity has all negative powers in the Laurent Series and acts chaotically unlike the others (e.g. see Picard's Theorem)

Comment: @boudreaux A singularity $a$ of an analytic function $f$ is removable if $f$ is bounded near $a$, so this is the first thing to check. $a$ is a pole of order $n$ if, roughly speaking, $f$ behaves like $(z-a)^{-n}$ near $a$. So in this case, $f(z)$ tends to infinity (from all directions) as you go to $a$, but $(z-a)^nf(z)$ is bounded near $a$. You could either try to show this directly, or you could try to do some algebra and write $f(z)$ as $z^n$ times some bounded term. Equivalently, $f$ has a pole of order $n$ at $a$ if $1/f$ has a zero of order $n$ at $a$. Hopefully this can get you started

Comment: @NazMiheisi alternatively, the first one has an essential singularity because it must have a singularity at infinity (entire and nonconstant) which is clearly not removable and cannot be a pole since the number of poles and zeros must be equal on a compact riemann surface such as $\mathbb C \cup \infty$

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Yes, of course, you're right. Sorry about that. I for some reason conviced myself that $z^2\sin(1/z^2))$ is analytic at $0$ and has an essential singularity at infinity rather than the other way around. Thank you for correcting me!

Comment: Thanks! For 2, what would the order of the pole be?